# Como criar um botão que ao ser clicado cria um novo elemento com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando resolver, mas estou com dificuldades, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Crie um botão que ao ser clicado cria um novo elemento em tela com a forma de um quadrado vermelho com 100px de altura e largura. Sempre que o botão for clicado um novo quadrado deve aparecer na tela.

```html
<div id="app">

  <button class="botao">Adicionar</button>
  <div class="box">
  </div>

</div>
<script>
  var btnElement = document.querySelector('button.botao').addEventListener("click", criarQuadrado);
  var newQuadrado = document.querySelector('div.box');
  newQuadrado.style.backgroundColor = red;
  newQuadrado.style.width = 100;
  newQuadrado.style.height = 100;


  function criarQuadrado() {
    btnElement.createElement(newQuadrado);



  }
</script>
```

<sup>[[image: screenshot do código]
Click para visualizar o screenshot do código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FqRn.png)</sup>

Comment: No seu código você só tem `red` (que nesse caso está atuando como um **identificador** que, como não está definido, lançará um `ReferenceError` de variável não definida). Você deve utilizar uma **[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)**, isto é, `"red"` (que é, de fato, um _"texto"_, e não um identificador).

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas alterações importantes no seu código.

1. Primeira coisa foi remover a div box da tela, ela deve aparecer apenas quando o usuario clicar no botão.
2. Repara que na função criarQuadrado eu criei o elemento e armazenei o elemento criado em uma variável, repara tbm que esse elemento ainda não existe no DOM.
3. Quando eu vou colocar a cor na div, eu preciso atribuir uma string para esse valor, no seu caso vc estava atribuindo uma variável global (red), repara que red é diferente de 'red', isso é muito importante.
4. Quando você for atribuir uma altura(height) ou largura(width), você precisa passar uma string pois precisamos saber qual unidade de medida, por isso passei '100px' e não 100 como vc estava passando.
5. E por ultimo, ao invés de usar o createElement, eu usei o appendChild passando como parametro a div que criamos dinamicamente após o clique...

Espero que tenha ajudado, qualquer dúvida pode me mandar um email que podemos conversar mais.

thiagomoraisrj@gmail.com

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <button class="botao">Adicionar</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    var btnElement = document.querySelector('button.botao');
    btnElement.addEventListener("click", criarQuadrado);

    function criarQuadrado() {
      var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      newDiv.style.width = '100px';
      newDiv.style.height = '100px';
      document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(newDiv)
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Nossa obrigada mesmo! Clareou muita coisa pra mim!

Comment: qualquer dúvida pode me chamar no email, bora codar!